# Resharper Live Template - aligning output

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

I have a ReSharper "Live Template" to create the Arrange-Act-Assert comments I use in my unit tests. The template looks like this:

```
// Arrange
$END$

// Act

// Assert
```

However, when I use it and expand it (by hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> after the template name, `aaa`) in an empty NUnit test method:

```
[Test]
public void TestXYZ() {
     aaa(Tab)
}
```

I get this result - which is not exactly what I had hoped for!

```
    [Test]
    public void TestXYZ() {
        // Arrange
        |            

// Act

// Assert
    }
```

I was hoping that the comments would be nicely aligned like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestXYZ() {
        // Arrange
        |            

        // Act

        // Assert
    }
```

Is there any trick I can use to get this result? I can't seem to find the "right" setting to tweak for this.... anyone else know what I'm missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the 'Reformat' option ticked when you define the template.

A better template would be to include the whole test method, something like:

```
[Test]
public void $UnitUnderTest$_$Criteria$_$ExpectedResult$()
{
    // Arrange
    $END$

    // Act

    // Assert
}
```

Comment: Thanks - the "Reformat" option is ticked, and I do also have a template for the whole test - but sometimes I just need the Act-Arrange-Assert comments so I'd like to get this to work, too